# SQL Server Report Builder Combining mutliple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have two data sets and they are related by an ID number. I am trying to generate a report where a row in table one will be used for a section header for all the related data in table two. That is kind of confusing, so here's some pictures.

**Data Set 1**

```
ID   Company  Total Sales
1    ACME      23000
2    AJAX      43222
3    STACK     56700
```

**Data Set 2**

```
ID  ITEM   DESC   QTY
1    A     ADESC   3 
1    B     BDESC   3
1    C     CDESC   4
2    D     DDESC   2
2    E     EDESC   4
3    F     FDESC   5
```

Here's what I am trying to get the report to look like.

```
1  ACME   23000
   A   ADESC   3
   B   BDESC   3
   C   CDESC   4
2  AJAX    43222
   D   DDESC   2
   E   EDESC   4
3  STACK   56700
   F   FDESC   5
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this in Report Builder. I'm pretty new to Report builder and am not sure what to look for here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are Table 1 and Table 2 database tables?

Comment: They are data sets in Report Builder.

Comment: really the only other way around it is to create a subreport and link the id's together... or you could simply create another dataset with all the required data you need, and group them in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer option 1 but I have 2 options to get you over the line.

**Option 1 - If the datasets come from the same database:**

Would be better if you created one SQL and included the header on all the detail rows. You want your SQL to produce the following:

```
ID  COMPANY  TOTAL SALES  ITEM  DESC   QTY
1    ACME     23000        A     ADESC  3 
1    ACME     23000        B     BDESC  3 
1    ACME     23000        C     CDESC  4 
2    AJAX     43222        D     DDESC  2
2    AJAX     43222        E     EDESC  4 
3    STACK    56700        F     FDESC  5
```

**Edit -**
Example SQL (un-optimised):

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( /*your data set 1 sql*/ ) DS1,
       ( /*your data set 2 sql*/ ) DS2
WHERE  DS1.ID = DS2.ID
```

Once this is done you should follow the tablix wizard and group by `Id`. To get the best out of the wizard I would only put the `Id` in the tablix and put the dataset 2 columns in the wizard as detail and finish the wizard.

Then insert columns into the group and add the dataset 1 columns.

**Option 2- If the datasets are on separate databases or can't be modified:**

Use dataset 2 as per the last option being sure to include the group by `Id`.

Then insert the other 2 columns and using the [`LookUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) or [`LookUpSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) function to extract the data from dataset 2.

Comment: All the values are coming from the same DB. The total_sales column is being generated by the SUM SQL function which is why it is in a separate table since I would have to include all the other columns in the group by clause.

Comment: @ReidMac, This is no problem, I've added an example sql based on the information here and is not optimised but will work never the less. You can use window functions but without the database scheme I can't speculate an example.